# Help with dirty viewfinder

Tags: nikon, maintenance, camera

I have a Nikon D5300 that I do not use anymore. I want to give it to my nephew on his birthday. However the viewfinder of the device is very dirty despite the amount of care I put into my gear. I have tried cleaning it with Q-Tips, small cotton slivers dipped in cleaning solution (wringed the excess solution out of it to avoid it leaking into the device). But it still refuses to be cleaned. Any suggestions on how to clean it? It has no warranty so sending it to the shop to be cleaned is no go. Any help?

EDIT:

Adding a picture to explain my problem a bit better. Sorry for the horrendous drawing quality, I don't have access to the camera at the moment as well.
[image]

Comment: I hope someone can clarify this in an answer [in case I ever get specks in mine] as I have nowhere near the expertise to fish fact from fiction in this, but I found a scary tale which basically said "ignore it or give it to Nikon to fix" - https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/3638182

Comment: Are you trying to clean the external part of the eyepiece or the internal focusing screen above the mirror inside the camera?

Comment: @MichaelClark the internal side of the external glass. i hope i am making some sense. :D

Comment: Have you taken the eyepiece apart to get to the internal side of it?

Comment: i don't think i can do that on my camera. give me a second. I'm adding some more information. :D

Comment: I'd be very, very surprised if you can access the internal side of the viewfinder without dissembling the camera in some fashion.

Comment: @mooie yep, I just gave it to the repair shop and it cost me a few bucks but was worth it

Answer (score 1):

Because it's a difficult and long (30 minutes) procedure I'll give links, we can't copy verbatim all the text and swipe the person's photos to provide an answer. Here are four very similar methods usable for similarly designed cameras.

- [Nikon D5000 Viewfinder Replacement](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Nikon+D5000+Viewfinder+Replacement/25549)
- [How to Open/Dismantle Your Nikon D3200 and Clean the Viewfinder](http://cobytechtutorials.blogspot.ca/2014/02/how-to-opendismantle-your-nikon-d3200.html?m=1)
- [Nikon D5100 Teardown](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Nikon+D5100+Teardown/5271)
- [Nikon D5300 DIY Digital Infrared Conversion Tutorial](https://www.lifepixel.com/tutorials/infrared-diy-tutorials/life-pixel-nikon-d5300-diy-digital-infrared-conversion-tutorial) [exposes the viewfinder]

No disassembly information on the product page [Nikon D5300](http://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/products/25/D5300.html), a tiny bit of info about cleaning the sensor.